# Safari Canvas Percentage Font Size

Tags: html, canvas, safari

I have a draggable / resizable canvas element contained within a div.
When the div is expanded, the canvas element is too.
The canvas element has some text -> `context.font("100% Impact");`.
Every browser renders it fine, but Safari seems to display same sized text no matter what percentage value I put in.
50% renders the same 100% renders the same as 1000%...

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I tried defining initial font size on the html and body =>

```
html, body { font-size: 16px; }
```

but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

One reason `might be` because your font size is smaller than the minimum acceptable by 'user'

On: `Safari-Preferences-Advanced tab` 
it's an option `Universal access - never use font sizes smaller than....`

So no matter what font-size you set it will never be smaller than that limit